# What is a vegan recipe for lasagne?

Tags: substitutions, vegan, lasagna

Do you guys have any idea how much I am craving a good old piece of lasagne. Since my girlfriend is vegan I wanna make the lasagne her way, of you now what I mean.

So any ideas how to best substitute the meat and still get the amazing lasagne taste we all love?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Josef.  This question will likely be closed, because we don't answer recipe requests.  However, take a tour of the site, look at the rules, and we look forward to your future contributions.

Comment: Moscafj, you can't do this to me!

Comment: I neither make the rules, nor do I enforce them.  I am just a voting member of a community.

Comment: All good man! No hard feelings ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Holy Cow Vegan is a great site for vegan recipes. Check out their vegan lasagna recipe https://holycowvegan.net/classic-vegan-lasagna/

I have also used traditional lasagna recipes and substituted the cheese with a non-dairy alternative and if it calls for meat I've used a meat substitute such as ground meatless or mushrooms instead of meat.

Comment: See my comment above.  See, the problem is, this results in a long list of everyone's favorite websites and recipes.  This is not what the community was designed for.  We welcome you to the community, and look forward to your participation, but please take a tour and learn how we work.